# How to fix Invalid worldAABB?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
public class path : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Line renderer veriables")]
    public LineRenderer line;
    [Range(2, 30)]
    public int resolution;
    Rigidbody rb;
    [Header("Formula variables")]
    public Vector3 velocity;
    public float yLimit;
    private float g;

    [Header("Linecast variables")]
    [Range(2, 30)]
    public int linecastResolution;
    public LayerMask canHit;
    public Rigidbody ballRigid;
   
    public open2close claw;
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        g = Mathf.Abs(Physics.gravity.y);
    }

    private void Update()
    {


        if(claw.isClosed)
            RenderArc();
        
       
    }

    private void RenderArc()
    {
        
        line.positionCount = resolution + 1;
        line.SetPositions(CalculateLineArray());
    }

    private Vector3[] CalculateLineArray()
    {
        Vector3[] lineArray = new Vector3[resolution + 1];

        var lowestTimeValueX = MaxTimeX() / resolution;
        var lowestTimeValueZ = MaxTimeZ() / resolution;
        var lowestTimeValue = lowestTimeValueX > lowestTimeValueZ ? lowestTimeValueZ : lowestTimeValueX;

        for (int i = 0; i < lineArray.Length; i++)
        {
            var t = lowestTimeValue * i;
            lineArray[i] = CalculateLinePoint(t);
        }

        return lineArray;
    }

    private Vector3 HitPosition()
    {
        var lowestTimeValue = MaxTimeY() / linecastResolution;

        for (int i = 0; i < linecastResolution + 1; i++)
        {
            RaycastHit rayHit;

            var t = lowestTimeValue * i;
            var tt = lowestTimeValue * (i + 1);

            if (Physics.Linecast(CalculateLinePoint(t), CalculateLinePoint(tt), out rayHit, canHit))
                return rayHit.point;
        }

        return CalculateLinePoint(MaxTimeY());
    }

    private Vector3 CalculateLinePoint(float t)
    {
        float x = rb.velocity.x * t;
        float z = rb.velocity.z * t;
        float y = (rb.velocity.y * t) - (g * Mathf.Pow(t, 2) / 2);
        return new Vector3(x + transform.position.x, y + transform.position.y, z + transform.position.z);
    }

    private float MaxTimeY()
    {
        var v = rb.velocity.y;
        var vv = v * v;

        var t = (v + Mathf.Sqrt(vv + 2 * g * (transform.position.y - yLimit))) / g;
        return t;
    }

    private float MaxTimeX()
    {
        if (IsValueAlmostZero(rb.velocity.x))
            SetValueToAlmostZero(ref velocity.x);

        var x = rb.velocity.x;

        var t = (HitPosition().x - transform.position.x) / x;
        return t;
    }

    private float MaxTimeZ()
    {
        if (IsValueAlmostZero(rb.velocity.z))
            SetValueToAlmostZero(ref velocity.z);

        var z = rb.velocity.z;

        var t = (HitPosition().z - transform.position.z) / z;
        return t;
    }

    private bool IsValueAlmostZero(float value)
    {
        return value < 0.0001f && value > -0.0001f;
    }

    private void SetValueToAlmostZero(ref float value)
    {
        value = 0.0001f;
    }

    public void SetVelocity(Vector3 velocity)
    {
        this.velocity = velocity;
    }

}
```

I have this code but for some reason it shows these errors:

*Invalid AABB a
*Invalid AABB a
*UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
*Assertion failed on expression: 'IsFinite(outDistanceForSort)'
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

My trajectory isnt even showing anymore. ANyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I think the issue here might be that you are passing two positions into the `Physics.Linecast` that are too close to each other.

Comment: Hmm how would you try to fix this ?

Comment: In my case it happened because one of the Vector3s in my `LineRenderer`'s positions had a `NaN` in it. I guess the LineRenderer code internally uses the AABB related code that is typically used by Physics subsystem.